# Restricting SSH to ECDSA

Tags: linux, ssh

I am changing my sshd_config to deny RSA.
I have the following line where I removed RSA, which I thought would do so: `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ecdsa-sha2*` however I can still ssh in via RSA unless I remove `ssh-rsa` from this line `HostKeyAlgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ssh-rsa`

Is that correct? What is the point of taking it out of `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` if it still works anyway?

Comment: because this has to do with configuring a service, I'm migrating to a more appropriate site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` is not related to the host keys, but to the authentication keys. Therefore you can initiate the connection to the server, but can't authenticate with your RSA key.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to understand: I should be able to get the initial ssh prompt but my password shouldn't work? I can log in find from my PC using RSA so it is still authenticating hmm.

Comment: No. This is completely unrelated to any passwords. We are talking about Public key authenticateon == passwordless.

Comment: @Paul: The part you're missing is that SSH does two completely different authentications: first the client authenticates the server's hostkey, then the server authenticates the client's password or pubkey. Both are configured via independent options.

Comment: @grawity Thanks guys, it makes way more sense now!